# multiple .net core SDK (of different versions) installed, can I just keep the latest?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I've been using Visual Studio Community IDE to develop some apps lately, and I just saw multiple .NET Core SDK with slightly different minor version updates installed on my desktop. (possibly installed along with the VS updates pushed by Microsoft)

Question:
**can I just keep the latest version? (e.g. 2.1.103 in the case).**

or I have to keep all these versions (~460MB each in size) to keep the Visual Studio working, which is insane considering that my SSD is running out of free space (eventually)...

[image: multiple .net core SDKs installed]

Comment: Are you even developing in .net core 2.1?  Chances are you'll be fine to delete all but the latest.  You can always reinstall if you need one.

Answer (score 28):

The answer is yes you can. If you'd like to try it out, simply uninstall everything and reinstall the latest SDK from https://dot.net. It'll work. Make sure you keep the one you need though, because if your own project's declaration is specifying the SDK, you NEED that specific SDK. But there's a catch, scroll down.

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4241

Quoted from Bill Wagner,

> In summary, the .NET Core SDK is backwards compatible and the newest
>   one on the box is used unless there is a global.json file that
>   indicates another version of the SDK.
>
> So, the short answer is:
>
> - You need the one you want to run (latest suggested and previews
>     should be fine)   *   And, any that are specified in global.json
>
> If a SDK version is in a global.json on your machine, and you do not
>   have that version, you will roll forward across patch, but not feature
>   versions of the SDK. Except that the roll forward behavior is overly
>   aggressive in the the 2.1.x -> 2.1.300 range. For that range, we
>   recommend you not do roll forward but have the specified version
>   available.

**The catch is here.**

> One correction.
>
> By the time 2.1.300 ships, we will not rollforward from 2.1.x to
>   2.1.300. We will keep within the boundaries of the release.
>
> So:
>
> 2.1.x => 2.1.1, 2.1.9, 2.1.10…
>   2.1.100 => 2.1.100, 2.1.101, 2.110…
>   2.2.200 > 2.1.200, 2.1.201,…

As quoted by Kathleen Dollard, you need to follow this guideline to develop on specific versions of the SDK according to your project/s.

To check your current machine's SDKs installed on macOS:

```
 ✘ nixholas@Nicholass-MacBook-Pro  ~/Projects/nozomi   staging  dotnet --list-sdks
1.0.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
1.0.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.0.0-preview2-006497 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.104 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.300-rc1-008673 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.301 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.400 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.402 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.500 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.2.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.2.103 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.2.104 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.2.105 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.2.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.2.301 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Comment: I dont see global.json in my project created in core 2.0 also verified by clean new project in 2.2, it wasn't there, is global.json was something like used to come before ? and if Yes, what if I simply deletes this from my app, then latest SDK or runtime will work for all versions, correct ?