# .NET confused, too many files

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a server running tons of apps like IIS, VS, VS Code etc. Can someone tell me what these folders are:

```
%programfiles%\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App
```

I have an old version of .NET Core but .NET Core uninstall tool cannot find it, it doesn't even show up in add or remove program.

Can I download the latest binaries of the SDK and just swap the directories?

Answer (score 0):

1. `shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/<runtime version>` This framework contains the .NET runtime and supporting managed libraries.
2. `shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.{App,All}/<aspnetcore version>` contains the ASP.NET Core libraries. The libraries under `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` are developed and supported as part of the .NET project. The libraries under `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` are a superset that also contains third-party libraries.
3. `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref` describes the API of `x.y` version of Windows Desktop applications. These files are used when compiling for that target. This isn't provided on non-Windows platforms.

For more packaging details ,you can refer to this  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/distribution-packaging).

If you can't uninstall the old version of .net core, you can download the version you want and specify to use this version in your project. You can take a look at [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869580/multiple-net-core-sdk-of-different-versions-installed-can-i-just-keep-the-la).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned dotnet-core-uninstall tool cannot identify the present, either Windows. I think it was installed as a prerequisite of another application as VS & VS Code or IIS is installed on the server. 
My question is, if I download the latest binaries of SDK can I swap the three directories (mentioned in my post) with the updated ones from the downloaded binaries of SDK ? Or is this going to break anything? The current version present in the server is 3.0.3 and I am trying to update it 3.1.28

Comment: I tried putting the config file for version 3.1.28 into 3.0.3 and changing the folder name for 3.0.3 to 3.1.28 and it worked.@andynewfriends

Comment: Have you tried [this uninstall method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-windows)?

Comment: I tried everything as far as uninstalling, with no luck. I'm starting to thing if they are orphan files left behind. My concern is if a application installed on the server depends on those binaries. As I mentioned, this server is hosting all kinds of applications.